# SASS - font face not working with right path

Tags: css, sass

I recently started using SASS and I want to import 2 fonts, Montserrat and Open Sans. Normally in CSS, you do something along the lines of

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat'
    src: url('../../webfonts/Montserrat.ttf');
}
```

And it works just fine. If my file structure looks like the following

```
CSS
   Base
     typography.sass
Webfonts
   Montserrat.ttf
```

But I put the following code in my SASS file.

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Montserrat'
  src: url("../../webfonts/Montserrat.ttf")

@font-face
  font-family: 'Open Sans'
  src: url("../../webfonts/OpenSans.ttf")
  src: url("../../webfonts/OpenSans.ttf?iefix") format("embedded-opentype")
```

But the font's don't load. I tried similar question on this topic but none of them were succesfull for me. What could this problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your folder name is `Webfonts` and you reference it with `url("../../webfonts/...`, then you have your answer there (lowercase vs. uppercase w/W).

Also, your code example results in a double `src` attribute. I don't know if it is related to the problem.

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Open Sans'
  src: url("../../webfonts/OpenSans.ttf")
  src: url("../../webfonts/OpenSans.ttf?iefix") format("embedded-opentype")
```

The code above compiles to this, where the `src` overwrites itself for each time:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url("../../webfonts/OpenSans.ttf");
  src: url("../../webfonts/OpenSans.ttf?iefix") format("embedded-opentype");
}
```

The `src` attribute should only be set once, but with multiple values instead. I think this will work in Sass:

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Open Sans'
  src: url("../../webfonts/OpenSans.ttf"), url("../../webfonts/OpenSans.ttf?iefix") format("embedded-opentype")
```

Comment: The folder is called webfonts. The captical W was my fault but the code still does not work. It says `GET link net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not found)` while the path is correct